# Dynamic jndi-names

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

In my use case I use Remote EJBs along with glassfish-web.xml descriptor. Since I use beans from different instances, jndi-names specified need full IIOP address. I do not know at build-time what will those addresses be (application will be deployed for many clients who can have different node configurations).

Is there a way to dynamically, from classpath for example, fill those jndi names? Or make such a setup work in some other way, like having glassfish-web.xml equivalent in application code?